# How to shrink text on overflow in a pptx textbox with ReporteRs library (R)?

Tags: r, powerpoint, reporters

I'm trying to automate pptx creation in R using ReporteRs but I have problems with the textboxes. Although the template has the 'shrink text on overlow' option set, the pptx created has always marked the 'Do not Autofit' option.

It seems is a limitation of the library but if anybody knows how to solve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you know that the new CRAN version (0.8.6) should fix this issue.

```
install.packages("ReporteRs")
```

Comment: Hi David. The option is now selected but when the pptx is opened the text is not shrunk until any textbox in the document is edited. It make me not to use it but anyway, I vote your answer as OK. Thanks